# Como que excluir do resultado os campos multivalue que não batem com minha query?

Tags: apache-solr, lucene

Eu tenho alguns documentos indexados como o abaixo:

```
{
  "doc_desc": "Indexing Child Documents in JSON",
  "doc_id": "379",
  "image_id": [
          "28086# ho hum... this is page 1 of chapter 1",
          "28087# more text... this is page 2 of chapter 1",
          "28088# more text... this is page 3 of chapter 1"
      ]
}
```

Quando eu buscar por "ho hum", preciso que o documento retornado seja algo como:

```
{
      "doc_desc": "Indexing Child Documents in JSON",
      "doc_id": "379",
      "image_id": [
              "28086# ho hum... this is page 1 of chapter 1"
       ]
}
```

Então eu posso saber exatamente qual página contêm as palavras que eu estava procurando. Como posso fazer isso?

Em outras palavras... Como que eu excluo do resultado os campos multivalue que não batem com minha query?

OBS: solr-4.10.2 e um data-import (db-data-config.xml) do meu banco de dados SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um ticket aberto no JIRA do Solr desde 2012 para o desenvolvimento dessa funcionalidade, mas ainda está aberto e sem resolução.

[Solr: Return only matched multiValued field](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3955)

Por enquanto isso ainda não é possível de ser feito com o Solr nativo.